# How to show images put with the editor

Tags: strapi

I have a text with a image that I put with the WYSIWYG editor. When It goes to preview the imagem is shown perfectly but when I consume the API, I get just a text with the link inside it, and it is show broken like that

```
![text]( https://res.cloudinary.com/rodolphonetto/image/upload/v1564945137/jekrcusr6jz1mfubb6jm.jpg) Coloquei uma foto diferente só pra testar como funciona colocar fotos aleatóriamente no meio do texto =)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WYSIWYG return content in markdown format.

See here https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/

If you want to insert it in your application, you will have to use a convertor from makdown to html for example.